# How to change email id in joomla which is in equiry form?

Tags: php, email, joomla

I am using Joomla Website.

In my website i got Enquiry & Registration Form menu.

Customer fill that form online i will get all details through my mail.

Now i want change email id, where can i find setup to change email id.

Comment: Which version of Joomla you are using ?

Comment: Joomla! version, 2.5.11.

Comment: What component or module you using for enquiry form ? Go to menu try editing that page & see on the right side panel you might get something helpful.

Comment: i cant see any option to change emial ID,..

Comment: Please oh please update to Joomla 2.5.19. You are 8 versions behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Joomla default `com_contact` component for your inquiry form.

the Go to `Admin -> components -> Com_contact -> Edit your inquiry form`

set the email Id on the right side contact details section.

Hope its helps..

Comment: hi thanx for ur time,... i have changed email id as you specified above, but mails are still going to old email id.

Comment: is that using com_contact component ? make sure its not hard coded in the controller check this too  components/com_contact/controllers/contact.php your form submitting task.